# TSQL, How to get smalldatetime's time between two smalldatetime's times?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have Table with two smalldatetime columns, where one is startTime and other one is endTime.
I need to select all values from table which between times of both columns compared to getdate()' time.

I'm using SQL-Server 2005.

example

- startTime    endTime       value1
- 2/2/**01** 16:00 2/2/**01** 18:00  1
- 2/2/**01** 21:00 2/2/**01** 22:00  2
- 2/2/**01** 05:00 2/2/**01** 22:00  3

select getdate() gives 2/2/**03** 21:40 **time is the only important factor**

so i need to get 2 and 3

thanks in advance

Comment: @Lieven, i've meant value1 should return 2 and 3. Of course value1=1 is excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT value1
      FROM tableA
     WHERE CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108) 
   BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar, Table_1.StartDate, 108) 
       AND CONVERT(varchar, Table_1.EndDate, 108);
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE getdate() BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

**EDIT**

You should have a lok at this link

and try something like [Date/Time Conversions Using SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1145)

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        startDate smalldatetime,
        endDate smalldatetime,
        value1 int
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '02 Feb 2010 16:01', '02 Feb 2010 18:00', 1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '02 Feb 2010 21:00', '02 Feb 2010 22:00', 2
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '02 Feb 2010 05:00', '02 Feb 2010 22:00', 3

DECLARE @MyGetDate DATETIME

SELECT @MyGetDate = '2 Mar 2003 21:40'

SELECT  * 
FROM @Table
WHERE convert(varchar, @MyGetDate, 14) BETWEEN convert(varchar, startDate, 14) AND convert(varchar, endDate, 14)
```

Comment: I'm interested in time check only, date doesn't really matters

Comment: thanks for effort but @Ardman's solution seems shorter and more readable

Comment: I just want to ask. Emm... but what if just to make such kind of statement WHERE convert(varchar, a_table_date_col, 14) BETWEEN convert(varchar, startDate, 14) AND convert(varchar, endDate, 14) ? It didn't work for me but is it possible to ?

Answer (score 0):

and CONVERT(varchar, Table.column, 113) 
   BETWEEN '06 Jun 2016 14:00:00:000' AND '07 Jun 2016 08:00:00:000'

Comment: Should have been  Where CONVERT(varchar, Table.column, 113) BETWEEN '06 Jun 2016 14:00:00:000' AND '07 Jun 2016 08:00:00:000'

Comment: why dont you edit the Question instead of adding a comment?

Answer (score 0):

In case if this may help anyone, I am giving a solution I used to get said values-

my table 'mw_shift' looks like this-

[image]

note: columns 'ftime' and 'ttime' are having TIME (datatype)

now following select command gives you the desired value-

```
select name from mw_shift where CONVERT(time,'10:32:00') between ftime and ttime 

select name from mw_shift where CONVERT(time,'20:32:00') between ftime and ttime 

select name from mw_shift where CONVERT(time,'00:32:00') between ftime and ttime
```